# Using Azure Active Directory with aspnetcore app

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to get up to speed using Azure Active Directory with an aspnetcore 5.0 web app.

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) tutorial, and it seems to work fine:  That is, I start the app, and it then shows the Active Directory Login, and I log in with my Microsoft Account.

I then try to view the app as a logout out user.  So I log out.  However, when I do so, I am directed back to the Active Directory login again.  It seems there is no way to view the app unless I am logged in.

Instead, I would like to see the login prompt only when I click the Login link.  And I should be able to view the app after logging out.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use custom [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to redirect by checking the Homepage path.

For Example, In `app.UseMvc` use below code:

```
app.UseRewriter(
    new RewriteOptions().Add(
        context => { if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path == "/AzureAD/Account/SignedOut")
            { context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index"); }
        })
);
```